# How do I add a vertical separator line between 3 displayed values?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I have 3 values displayed consecutively on the screen and I need to add 2-3 vertical separator lines between all of them.The issue is everytime I add a view/ divider between them they shift to the left or right way too much and some values cut off/ disappear. I was wondering if there is a way to go abotu it, below is my xml code for the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.justin.abc"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <com.justin.abc.utils.FontView
                android:id="@+id/symbol"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                foo:customFont="Roboto-Bold.ttf" />

            <com.justin.abc.utils.FontView
                android:id="@+id/arrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                foo:customFont="Roboto-Bold.ttf" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/value1_back"
                style="@style/abc.TextView.ListsTextView.Header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="3dp"/>

            <com.justin.abc.utils.FontView
                android:id="@+id/change"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                foo:customFont="Roboto-Bold.ttf" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <com.justin.abc.utils.FontView
                android:id="@+id/symbol2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                foo:customFont="Roboto-Bold.ttf" />

            <com.justin.abc.utils.FontView
                android:id="@+id/dashboard_markets_arrow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                foo:customFont="Roboto-Bold.ttf" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/value2_back"
                style="@style/abc.TextView.ListsTextView.Header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="3dp"/>

            <com.justin.abc.utils.FontView
                android:id="@+id/change2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                foo:customFont="Roboto-Bold.ttf" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <com.justin.abc.utils.FontView
                android:id="@+id/dashboard_markets_symbol3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                foo:customFont="Roboto-Bold.ttf" />

            <com.justin.abc.utils.FontView
                android:id="@+id/dashboard_markets_arrow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                foo:customFont="Roboto-Bold.ttf" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/value3_back"
                style="@style/abc.TextView.ListsTextView.Header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="3dp"/>

            <com.justin.abc.utils.FontView
                android:id="@+id/change3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                foo:customFont="Roboto-Bold.ttf" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Do I need to add a layer or something in the background for it to support the same or do I need to change this structure? 
Thanks!
Justin
[image: I have attached the image for the same]

even after adding android:gravity="center" I still see the same results

Comment: Could you post an image of what it looks like now and what you want it to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gru says, you can get the black line using a View between `layout1` and `layout2` *and* `layout2` and `layout3`.

As you point out, this will be on the left edge of the contents of `layout2` and `layout3`. To separate this out a bit, an easy solution is to add the line:

```
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
```

to `layout1`, `layout2` and `layout3`, whilst removing it from the top `LinearLayout`. This won't achieve precise centring, but it will give an equal text to left edge for each block, which I think will look about right.

Comment: I have added the image in the edited question for the same and even after adding the above line it still sticks to the left line as seen in the image, are there any other adjustments that can help push it? like padding or something?

Comment: OK, got it, I'll have a think about how to achieve what you want.

Comment: What is `FontView` a derivative of and how does it set it's width?

Comment: its a custom font class to set certain types of fonts

Comment: thanks!followed that and adjusted accordingly,  paddingleft to 30 worked, thanks for the help, i appreciate it!

Comment: do you have any idea about this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382510/how-do-i-fix-the-password-username-authentication-in-my-code/18428135?noredirect=1#18428135

Comment: you are good at these UI questions, so have one more for ya: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166342/how-do-i-avoid-double-borders-between-lists/19201562?noredirect=1#comment28459924_19201562 Let me know if you have any idea about the same?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, that question appears to have been solved!

Comment: sorry about that, I posted this comment before someone posted an answer to it. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Place this in between each value you have mentioned in your question.

`<View android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="2px"
    android:background="#000000"/>`

should give you a black bar in between values.

Comment: I tried that but it just sticks to the values on the left, if I add any padding, it shifts the values, i want it to be centered, so it can be equidistant between these values, any clue?

Comment: @Justice Bauer for this check Neil Townsend answer, may that help you.