# How do I fix a moving checkbox?

Tags: android

I am using a checkbox in my code that is grayed out if not enabled by default. Here is the code for the same:

```
public View getView(final Context context, View view) {
    if (view == null) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_selectable_textview, null);
    }

    final CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.selectable_text);
    textView.setText(mCategoryName);

    if (isDefault()) {
        mIsSelected = true;
    }

    textView.setChecked(mIsSelected);
    if(!isEnabled()){
        textView.setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_selected_grayout);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checkboxline);
        textView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    }
    return view;
}
```

The checkbox_selected_grayout is the image for checkbox and the xml for checkboxline is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#202020"
                android:endColor="#202020"
                android:angle="360.0" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="40dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#414141" />
            <size android:height="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The checkbox looks fine when I am navigating to the view with checkbox, However when I scroll to the bottom of the view and return to the top, it appears to be shifting to the right and not aligned with the other check boxes, Any clue on how to fix it?
Note: As soon as I remove layerlist and switch ti to a single shape, it works fine without any shifts.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with strange looking stuff after scrolling up and down are often related to the reusing of views in a ListView. If you format an element in a ListView you always have to format everything, don't rely on  it being left "default", because it might have been reused and already formatted for another item.

in your code you have

```
!isEnabled()...
```

but you don't format those elements if it is enabled.